# IF ELSE in subquery SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, if-statement, subquery

I have 2 tables as below, and insert data into `ftable` from `f_table` accordingly. I want to insert `field_3` into `field3` if `field_3` exists, else insert `field_4` into `field3`.

How do I do that? Much appreciate for any reply.

```
CREATE TABLE ftable
(
field1 int null,
field2 int null,
field3 char(1)
);

CREATE TABLE f_table
(
field_1 int null,
field_2 int null,
field_3 char(1),
field_4 char(1)
);

INSERT INTO ftable (field1, field2, field3) 
    SELECT (field_1, field_2, field_3) 
    FROM f_table;
```

Comment: What do you mean by *if `field_3` exists* ? The column is part of the table - it **always** exists ....

Comment: whether the data of field_3 exists. Sorry for confusing u.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure what you really mean by *if `field_3` exists* - since it's part of the table, that column **always** exists...

Guessing that you probably mean: if it's `NOT NULL` - in that case, use this `CASE` statement:

```
INSERT INTO ftable (field1, field2, field3) 
    SELECT 
       field_1, field_2, 
       CASE
           WHEN field_3 IS NOT NULL THEN field_3
           ELSE field_4
       END
    FROM f_table;
```

**Update:** as per w0lf's suggestion, you could also use:

```
INSERT INTO ftable (field1, field2, field3) 
    SELECT 
       field_1, field_2, 
       ISNULL(field_3, field_4)
    FROM f_table;
```

Makes it a bit more compact - but a tad less readable, in my opinion. But this will work just fine - if `field_3` is NULL, then `field_4` is inserted instead.

Comment: I think it would be eaasier to use `isnull` instead

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you mean `field_3` being `NULL`, this is a good place to use `COALESCE`:

```
INSERT INTO ftable (field1, field2, field3) 
SELECT field_1, field_2, COALESCE(field_3,field_4) 
FROM f_table;
```

[`COALESCE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx):

> Returns the first nonnull expression among its arguments.